# Annual time series count data where the dependent variable is a count averaging 3,000 and no zeros

Tags: time-series, count-data

I need your assistance on time series count data. I got some annual time series data I want to run, however the dependent variable is a count (number of deaths) while the independent variables are either continuous or discrete. Ideally count data is modeled using standard Poisson or NB model (mostly its usually cross sectional data) or panel Poisson or panel NB for panel data. For time series the use of the standard models of Poisson or NB will not take care of serial correlation according to literature I have reviewed by Cameron and Trivedi (1999), Quddus (2008) and others (see attached documents). They therefore recommend the use of other versions of the models eg INAR(1) models. However, none of the literature explains how exactly this is to be done in any of the soft wares. Stata 13 does not avail that option neither does Eviews 5 (softwares that I have access to). How then is it to be executed? Or which command or adjustment to the standard models are to be applied when running the data? Or is it just a matter of including a lag of Y as an explanatory variable and executing Poisson? And will that get me a value for the binomial thinning operator?

I have tested for stationarity and found that my dependent count variable is I(0) while the independent variables are either I(0), I(1) or I(2). How then do I proceed if I cannot use standard Poisson or NB and neither can I use other time series models such as ARIMA because of the normality assumption which allow for negative values?

Your quick guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any help out there please? still stuck!